# How to figure out why my receptacle is reading 355 in bathroom and my ac quit working

Tags: hot-water

I'm trying to figure out why I'm having electrical problems - hot water heater bursting in flames, switch a light in closet on and it starts to smoke, popping breakers on certain receptacles, and AC stopped working.
I located a receptacle in the 2nd bathroom with one black showing 355V, a white coming out one on-side entering the second with no break, just looped around neutral on the switch receptacle combo and then a red shows nothing.
I looked behind the wall where the AC is panel with just 2 hots feeding no ground or white. Then out of breaker it's got a 4 wire line not using its neutral, its free hanging with end taped off and the ground itself taped to wall and two hots, leaving the same breaker two more house leaving no ground or neutral. How ?

Comment: Where are you at?

Comment: If electrical appliances are bursting into flames, your best bet is to shut off the electricity to the whole residence (if you can safely do so) and immediately call emergency services. Fire department to make _sure_ the fire is out, then the power company to ensure there's nothing _major_ wrong at the service drop, then a professional, licensed electrician to sort out what the heck is wrong. Based on your description, something is **seriously** wrong!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems like it's well beyond the scope of "DIY" work. This problem needs the attention of a licensed professional electrician to ensure that everything is sorted out properly so the OP's whole house doesn't burn down.

Comment: I agree that you should shut everything off in the short-term, but I'm confused by some of your description and some here might be able to point out problems if you posted some photos of the box in question and your breaker panel (with the cover off). It sounds extremely unusual for a US installation, so your location could help as well, please [edit] the question to give us more info.

Answer (score 4):

If you're seeing voltages that shouldn't be possible at the main panel, call the power company and tell them.  They will be very interested!

If you're not seeing it at the main panel start turning stuff off until the situation improves.

Comment: If that is stuff is happening, think I would get out and call for fire and shut off.  Would not bother with any more testing till afterwards.

Comment: yeah that's  why i lead with "call the power company." there's a small chance that this is actually some combination of local faults, and given that Joshua has already expressed the ability to measure voltages I felt that a little further diagnosis may be helpful to eliminate that possibility.